# convert Remix Artifact to truffle artifact

Tags: truffle, remix

how to convert a artifact file of a deployed ethereum smart contract, created in remix:
[image]

to a truffle artifact :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For artifact conversion, I would just suggest to delete all pairs from the remix artifact keeping only the "abi" pair, and also adding a "contractName" pair as follows:

```json
{
  "contractName": "StakDrop3",
  "abi": [...]
}
```

Comment: not sure, since the networks{ ... } part is also important since it houses the contract address, txhash of contract creation etc.

Comment: Yes, but you could alternatively manually point the artifact to a deployed address in the code.

Comment: Depends on your preference. I'm actually against sharing Truffle artifacts via GotHub repository since those expose some info about your build environment like machine name and such.

Comment: no the idea is to use truffle artifact in dapp so that the contract address can be directly read from the artifact itself. we cant do that in remix artifact, coz it doesnt hold the contract address right?

Comment: But there is still a way to convert those network addresses to the Truffle format. Maybe someone else could provide a more comprehensive answer, since I've stopped using Truffle in favor of Hardhat some time ago.

Comment: @Kombo For any dapp, you would only need the `{ "abi": [...] }` part of the artifact. I would suggest putting all deployed contract addresses in separate config files like `config/mainnet.json` according to the deployed network and manually pointing ABIs to them via Web3 or EthersJs. Don't make your DApp Truffle-dependent.